# Rationalizing fractions with multiple radicals

Tags: fractions

I am having trouble rationalizing $\frac{2}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}$

I have tried multiplying the fraction by $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}$ and got $\frac{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ I am not sure if that is correct or not  but I then multiplied by $\sqrt{2}$ but got stuck...

Assuming that I did the problem correctly so far, how would I multiply $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$ with $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: But $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt 2}\sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2} = \sqrt{4 - 2} = \sqrt 2$. How did you get $4- \sqrt 2$? And $2 \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2}\sqrt 2 = 2 \sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Could you explain how you multiplied $\sqrt{2}$ with $2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of multiplying top and bottom by $\sqrt{2}$, note that $2=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2$, so that $$\frac{2\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: Does this mean that 'rationalizing' means getting rid of radicals only in the denominator, but not in the whole expression?

Comment: Yes. We talk about "rationalizing the denominator" of a fraction with radicals in the denominator. Having a rational (integer, really) denominator makes arithmetic easier. We can't necessarily get rid of *all* the radicals, though, as we saw in this case. *If we're lucky*, we can get rid of all of the radicals--for an easy example, consider $\frac{\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{2}}$--but most of the time we'll still have some hanging around.

Comment: Ok that's cool.